Should a constructor with a std::initializer_list be explicit?
I am designing a container (yeah, do not reinvent the wheel, I know). Let's call it Container<T>.
I have a constructor to allow the initial number of elements:
explicit Container(std::size_t size);

And I want to implement an initializer_list constructor:
Container(std::initializer_list<T> param);

I know the rule of having every one parameter constructors marked as explicit, but then, since the std::initializer_list could be one element, it should be marked as explicit too.
Another point of problem is what will happen with a Container<std::size_t> and
Container<std::size_t> c{4UL};

And what about deduction guides?
So, what is the best practice or standard accepted way of dealing with explicit when std::initializer_list, and explicit conversion constructors and/or deduction guides are involved?
NOTE: By the best way/standard way I mean the way that is more used by the industry and/or recommended by static checkers, or ISO C++ standard.

Container<std::size_t> c{4UL}; will select the initializer_list constructor.

To avoid ambiguity, using tag constructor might help.

@Jarod42 will that change making the initializer_list constructor explicit?

You are explicit here. With explicit, code like return {4UL}; cannot select explicit constructors.

just copy the standard library, std::vector doesn't use explicit https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

when braces are used initializer_list overload has higher priority over other constructor overloads, so even Container<char> c{4UL}; will use initializer_list overload. When parenthesis are used then initializer_list should appear explicitly.

I would use std::span or mor generally, std::ranges::view auto as the initializer. initializer_list IMO pretty outdated, and ugly in a lot of ways.
